# doxygen reference from enum/class to function in file

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have code in c/c++

```
/**
 * Enumeration of the parameters to be requested by method #getParameter(Param)
 */
enum Param {
...
```

where `void getParameter(Param param)` is defined in the same file `main.cpp` as `enum Param`. 
Doxygen `1.8.16` cannot reference the reference `#getParameter(Param)`. 
I tried also with `main.cpp#getParameter(Param)`. 
By the way, same if i use `getParameter(char)`.

I am coming from java where every method is within a class/interface/enum or that like, 
but never directly in a file, so that this case does not occur. 
If i want to reference the enclosing class, i just have to give it. 
Hm.. would be the according file here. 
But this idea was not successful.

Interesting enough, just writing `main.cpp` creates a reference to the file properly.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What happens when you just use `getParameter` or `#getParameter`?

Comment: i added to the version to the question: 1.8.16

Comment: @albert: getParameter just prints the text without warning, which is clear, whereas #getParameter does not resolve the link either. Now I tried even #getParameter(char)  (added an according function of course), same.

Comment: Please add an complete example and the differences from the default doxygen configuration file (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`).

Comment: Maybe also try class_name::getParameter